# Caching Google calendar credentials or service

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have the following code to build a Google calendar service with the Java API (using a service account):

```
/**
 * Return a google Calendar object for interacting with the calendar API.
 * Return null if it can't be built for any reason
 */
private Calendar buildGoogleCalendarService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    String googleUsername = this.getGoogleUsername();
    if (googleUsername == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String path = AuthManager.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
    File privateKey = new File(path + "/google_key.p12");
    if (!privateKey.exists()) {
        logger.error("Google private key not found at " + privateKey.getAbsolutePath());
        return null;
    }
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setServiceAccountId(AppProperties.googleAppEmailAddress)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(privateKey)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
            .setServiceAccountUser(googleUsername).build();
    Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(AppProperties.appName).build();
    return service;
}
```

It works fine with some basic testing, the question is how long will the credentials / service be able to be re-used for? i.e. how many API requests can you make using it before regenerating? This server application may process a high volume of API calls and last for some months between reboots.

Doing some timing, the credential building stage (GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()...) takes the most time, approx. a quarter of a second, I'll try caching that to start with and see how it goes but any answers appreciated.

Comment: Service can be re used as long as the access token is valid, It is short-lived token, so request for refresh tokens(by selecting offline_type='refresh') check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer . Each application has a quota(Default) for each API. This decides on how many requests can be made to each API. check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't specifying an access token directly, `GoogleCredential` will refresh the token automatically. You already appear to be following [the OAuth 2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), so nothing more is necessary.